# What is the meaning of "to" in the sentence, "We awoke to the sound !"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "to" in the sentence, "We awoke to the sound!"?

Does "We awoke to the sound" mean "We awoke because of the sound(We awoke for the sound) ?

Does "to" in the sentence mean "because of" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [*to*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to_1):

> 20. *preposition*
>       You use **to** when indicating that two things happen at the same time.
>       For example, if something is done to music, it is done at the same time as music is being played.
>       *Romeo left the stage, **to** enthusiastic applause.
>
>       Amy woke up **to** the sound of her doorbell ringing.
>
>       'I've got an idea,' said Edward **to** a chorus of groans.*

As for:

> We awoke **to** the sound!

It means the sound could be heard as you woke up. But it is not specified whether the sound woke you up.